Did logic have an origin?
If the origin of logic was simultaneous to the origin of the universe how could the universe have a logical explanation to its origin?
If the origin of logic followed the origin of the universe how could there be a logical explanation to the origin of the universe?
If my argument is not flawed, what is the explanation of the origin of logic?
Is the only explanation that there was no origin to logic and the universe? or is the origin of logic and the universe only explainable by something outside of the universe, that is responsible for logic, and an explanation of the universe?

See Descartes on Eternal Truth

Maybe there is no "explanation to the origin of the universe". And what do you mean with "a logical explanation"? Logic is formal: it does not "explain" contingent facts.

You are mixing "logical" as partaining to formal logic: a discipline of its own, whose modern version is Mathematical Logic, which is mathematics, and "logical" as reasonable, based on evidence, etc.

@MauroALLEGRANZA maybe I'm mixing the idea of formal logic and Mathematics with as logic based on evidence. However if there is logic that determined the origin of the universe whether that was formal logic or evidence based logic would the application of either types of logic be able to explain the origin of the universe. If the universe was illogical, would we have the logic to determine it was illogical?

This question should not be closed. I read it as a deeply philosophical question, the question whether or not it is possible to have a theory of everything that encompasses itself (explains itself). The anthropic principle is one answer (a nonsensical answer imo, but still an answer). Believe in some kind of self-evident, necessarily existent abstract truths could be another answer (also nonsense imo). How to unravel the question is not trivial and still contentious.

@mudskipper At mudskipper I know I'm not as smart as the majority of people. I've just read the anthropic principle and the logic that the universe is sufficient to support the presence if life. Is brain dead logic and says nothing we would not be discussing this if the anthropic principle was false. Don't spare your reservation I'm man enough to know my place!!

The origin of logic is in the mind of God.

@HamSandwich you sound hungry why don't you eat the same as your name would suggest. I'm hungry but my pseudonym is  Jam sandwich so I don't get what you do.:-)

I love ham sandwiches. Thanks for the suggestion!

@HamSandwich So this conversation was mutually beneficial? :-)

Logic is a creation of minds.
Logic can be applied to any arguments that involve propositions. It does not matter that those propositions are about a subject that long predated our use of logic.

In attempting to ground science we have to ask what is basic in science, and that is the existence of things. So we ask what existence is, and we find Heidegger saying in regard to existence and reason:

"Only when we contemplated what λόγος meant for Heraclitus in early
Greek thinking did it become clear that this word simultaneously names
being and ground/reason, naming both in terms of their
belonging-together." The Principle of Reason, page 112.

So the calculative, rationalising principle is part of the mechanics that facilitates existence.
This is, of course, a form of existence that involves a 'living' exister which imparts subjective existence on comprehended things.  On the other hand, if we wish to consider physical matter without any living observers, this is a point of view which no-one has access to.
From the point of view where we do have existence then logic, λόγος, reasoning, is an intrinsic part of existence, from bio-mechanical logic to conscious thought.  And conceivably should also apply to subatomic processes and superpositions.

I can follow along with this up to your last sentence. When you say "And conceivably should also apply to subatomic processes and superpositions." I think you start mystifying your/Heidegger's earlier statements -- (similar to buying into the illusion that looking in a double mirror reveals an actual infinite).

@mudskipper I'll just recap: the being of Dasein (living existence) can attribute existence to things which then exist even when Dasein pays no mind. Living existence uses logic/reason to think, cells use logical molecular mechanics to function, atoms have processes which could be logically harnessed, quantum superpositions may play a part in the living existence of Dasein (e.g. Orch OR). So these logical processes are bound in with living existence. Furthermore, they (e.g. cellular logical mechanics) may be observed and then exist objectively. But the first understanding of logic is thinking.

This is in accordance with a definition of existence in which objective things need to be determined (by experience) to exist. Something completely undetermined isn't something that can said to exist, although the realist persuasion would say it exists even if one doesn't know what 'it' is. So there is a basic difference in definition there. The former, determining form of existence is determined by the exister, Dasein, who's living existence is bound up with logic all the way from physics to language. None of the processes that culminate in existence would get anywhere without logic.

I grant you all that. It's the words "conveivably ... also" that I objected too. Imo either you have already claimed this (since you made a universal statement) or you are mystifying what you just claimed. It seemed you did just want to make a universal statement.

Btw - what is kind of unclear to me is how this answer differs from positing the anthropic principle (in either weak or strong form). (So, perhaps I shouldn't have said that I can "follow along". I don't really know if I can.)

@mudskipper Heidegger's point is to use Dasein's form of existence as a working example, since it's convenient, and from there to ask what is existence (Being) generally. Since being comes before thought, it's kind of unthinkable experientially, but his approach is to orient the question ultimately to a non-anthropic conceptualisation of being. But yes, it is necessarily 'life'-centric, because that's where we have to start from. We don't have a comprehensive perspective from outside of life, e.g. is our origin the Big Bang, infinite cyclic multiverse or a determinate cogito ergo sum?

Are you arguing for pansychism? The proposition that all elements of the world are conscious? This is a phyicalist position in that a unit of consciousness is a unit of matter, and all life that exists can be distinguished with the product of this universal addition. Howver if you take a step back and  look at it, consciousness under this principle is  quantifiable, or you gain nothing other than a quantifiable measure of this or that. A fish is 26 and an ape is 35 and a human is 42.42 is designated by Douglas Adams as the solution to the ultimate question.Was he accurate in his calculation?

@8Mad0Manc8 By the time Heidegger has described the modes of being that constitute Dasein, being is not at all simple. For a start it includes Being-in-the-world, so there's a 'world' too. (Cogito ergo sum doesn't think in a vacuum.) And part of Dasein can be out of sight, as the call of conscience – still part of Dasein somehow. And it has possibilites still open. However, in contrast the existence of my coffee cup is fairly deliberately determined and not mysterious. The matter it's made of is a whole other mystery, always another layer it seems.

@ChrisDegnen Yeah all of that but does all of that Trump family and the importance of family, I hope you have family left and they support you  because logically the world is a shit hole if you don't have family. Sorry for my crude language.

@8Mad0Manc8 Maybe philosophy makes one more realistic in dealing with the crazy world. It leaves open mystery too, outlining the limits of concepts.

@ChrisDegnen Nobody can curl up to logic. Find a loving woman and reciprocate that love. On the face of it, it's cheesy, but the reality of it is not.

Logic - I think it's self-existent. Devising the principles of logic itself requires you to apply some other laws which are also based on some logical principles. So asking where these principles came from reversely will lead to infinite regress. Therefore some underlying principles should be self-existent which may be the most fundamental framework for logic for other logical principles to be built on. However, if the logic we know today is in its self fundamental, then voila! It should be self-existent per this line of reasoning.
